# git lfs checkout fails on windows with unicode path "Error: CreateFile"

Tags: windows, git, unicode, git-lfs, gitkraken

I have git for windows installed properly. Calling

```
git lfs checkout
```

using bash.exe on a path that contains special characters (C:\Users\myUser\öäü) fails with an error:

```
Error: CreateFile C:\Users\myUser\���: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I've tried checking out LFS files with GitKraken to the very same directory and it fails with the same error (I see that GitKraken invokes bash.exe as well). When using git-bash.exe I cannot reproduce the error. Both terminals are MINGW64, the locale of the bash.exe prints

```
$ locale
LANG=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

whereas git-bash.exe prints en_GB.UTF-8 instead. I've also tried so set

```
MSYSTEM=MINGW64
```

but that didn't help at all, unfortunately.
Using /usr/bin/mintty in Mingw-w64 mode fires up a functioning bash where I cannot reproduce the issue either. Hence I am wondering how I can configure bash.exe to function correctly, I feel that there must be some way to achieve that.

Edit:
git lfs version prints

```
git-lfs/2.12.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.15.1)
```

Calling git lfs checkout with GIT_TRACE=1 prints:

```
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git lfs checkout
14:12:20.043934 exec-cmd.c:237          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin
14:12:20.059555 git.c:704               trace: exec: git-lfs checkout
14:12:20.059555 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: git-lfs checkout
14:12:20.079718 trace git-lfs: exec: git 'version'
14:12:20.109504 trace git-lfs: exec: git '-c' 'filter.lfs.smudge=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.clean=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.process=' '-c' 'filter.lfs.required=false' 'rev-parse' '--git-dir' '--show-toplevel'
14:12:20.132914 trace git-lfs: exec: uname
14:12:20.189343 trace git-lfs: exec: cygpath '-w' '.git'
14:12:20.208415 trace git-lfs: exec: cygpath '-w' 'C:/Users/myUser/äöü'
14:12:20.243879 trace git-lfs: Error running 'git rev-parse': CreateFile C:\Users\myUser\���: The system cannot find the file specified.
Error: CreateFile C:\Users\myUser\���: The system cannot find the file specified.
...
```

Comment: What version of Git LFS are you using? `git lfs version` will tell you.

Comment: `git-lfs/2.11.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.14.2; git 48b28d97)`

Comment: I also tested the latest from your website `git-lfs/2.12.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.14.7; git dad7b9e6)`, same error

Comment: If you can provide a shell script that reproduces this in Git Bash, we'd love to see a bug report on the Git LFS issue tracker.

Comment: done: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/4227

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@bk2204 was able to fix it in git-lfs core, see: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/4227

As a workaround setting

```
LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
```

fixes the issue for me.